# Is there any way to open a program on a specific tty?

Tags: linux, command-line, ssh, tty

I have a PC with no mouse or keyboard, but it is connected to a monitor. I was wondering if is it possible to open a program remotely (like via SSH) in a specific tty (like tty1) so I would able to watch the output on the monitor.

Comment: What's wrong with just redirecting the output to the desired tty? Like `ls > /dev/tty1`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it seems like the following SO-question may answer yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994593/how-to-reroute-stdout-stderr-back-to-dev-tty

`exec >/dev/tty 2>&1` should do it

for only some commands  `> /dev/tty1` after the command (as stated by  David Schwartz) would also work

Answer (score 7):

You could use Linux [virtual consoles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console) for this. Each virtual console is a separate text-mode or graphical display, keyboard, and mouse, all sharing the computer's actual display hardware.

Each virtual console can be accessed through the tty devices `/dev/ttyN`, where N is 1, 2, etc. `/dev/tty1` is virtual console 1. If you had a keyboard attached to the computer, you'd press Alt-F1 to get to console 1, Alt-F2 for console 2, and so on (or Ctrl-Alt-FN if the currently-displayed console is running X). There is also a set of programs to work with virtual consoles which you'll have to use, since you don't have a keyboard.

In short:

```
some-program > /dev/tty1 2>&1
```

will redirect a program's output to virtual console 1. If console 1 isn't on the monitor, you can switch to it:

```
chvt 1
```

A better method is to run `openvt` to start a command on a virtual console:

```
openvt -s some-command
```

This will pick a new virtual console, make it visible on the screen, and run the specified command. Openvt has other options, so check the documentation.

Other useful commands are `fgconsole` to display the number of the currently-displayed console, and `deallocvt` to cleanup unused consoles.

All of these commands may require superuser privileges to run.